# ENOENT, no such file or directory - on building Android Cordova Project

Tags: android, netbeans, cordova-3, command-line-interface

I have created a Cordova Application Project using the CLI tool and NetBeans IDE for Cordova Project. I have also mapped the following path variables.

> ANDROID_HOME F:\AndroidProjects\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20131030\
>
> ANT_HOME C:\apache-ant-1.9.4\
>
> JAVA_HOME C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\
>
> PATH C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm;F:\Android Projects\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20131030\sdk\platform-tools\;F:\AndroidProjects\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20131030\SDK\TOOLS\;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\bin;%JAVA_HOME%\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin;%ANT_HOME%/bin;

I am also able to run the Demo Cordova Application on AVD and Real device,using eclipse. But, while trying to build the project with additional changes the CLI is giving me with the following error message

> [Error: ANDROID_HOME is set to a non-existant path: F:\Android
>   Projects\adt-bund le-windows-x86-20131030] Command finished with error
>   code 2: F:\CordovaProjects\CordovaAppOne\platforms\a
>   ndroid\cordova\build.bat Error:
>   F:\CordovaProjects\CordovaAppOne\platforms\android\cordova\build.bat:
>   Com mand failed with exit code 2
>       at ChildProcess.whenDone (C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_mo
>   dules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\src\cordova\superspawn.js:135:23)
>       at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17)
>       at maybeClose (child_process.js:756:16)
>       at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:823:5)

What should I set in addition to the above to resolve the error. I am using Windows8-64Bit on administrator account. Only Android platform has been added to the application using the CLI.

Answer (score 1):

Issue has been resolved. The issue was raised due to wrong pointing of ANDROID_HOME environment variable. It is required that the variable directly points to sdk folder itself instead of the Android Eclipse bundle.

Comment: For mine, it's: `C:\Users\viet\AppData\Local\Android\sdk` (I installed Android Studio)

Comment: Possible, glad the post helped. I haven't tried out with Android Studio yet.

Comment: after trying everything its the cordova update that worked for me :

npm update -g cordova

Comment: You are trying to update your package version or installing and setting up a new environment ?